# How can I prevent my Quicksort Algorithm from throwing a StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

Im trying to write a `quicksort` algorithm in C#, and I've been getting `System.StackOverflowExceptions` for the last while and can't figure out why.

Here is my Class:

```
    class quicksort : sortalgorithm
{
    int pivotIndex = -1;
    int pivotSwapped = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public quicksort(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.Length < 5)
        {
            throw new Exception("Array has too few Entries");
        }
        toSort = arr;
    }

    protected override int sort()
    {
        if (pivotIndex == -1) getPivot();
        int indexL = getIndexLeft();
        int indexR = getIndexRight();
        if (indexR != -1 && indexL != -1 && indexL != toSort.Length-1)
        {
            swap(indexL, indexR);
        }
        if (indexL > indexR)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index thingy");
            swap(toSort.Length - 1, indexL);
            pivotSwapped++;
            if (pivotSwapped == toSort.Length - 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("new piv");
                pivotSwapped++;
                getPivot();
                sort();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sort();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = toSort[i];
        toSort[i] = toSort[j];
        toSort[j] = temp;
    }

    private void getPivot()
    {
        pivotIndex = rand.Next(0, toSort.Length - 1);
        swap(toSort.Length - 1, pivotIndex);
    }

    private int getIndexLeft() // Larger then Pivot Starting: Left
    { //Error Here
        int itemFromLeft = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < toSort.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (toSort[i] >= toSort[toSort.Length - 1])
            {
                itemFromLeft = i;
                i = toSort.Length + 1;
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(itemFromLeft);
        return itemFromLeft;
    }

    private int getIndexRight()// Smaller then Pivot Starting: Right
    {
        int itemFromRight = -1;
        for (int i = toSort.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (toSort[i] < toSort[toSort.Length - 1])
            {
                itemFromRight = i;
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(itemFromRight);
        return itemFromRight;
    }
}
```

I hope that someone can help me.

P.S. the class `sortalgorithm` in this case only has the the array `toSort`.

My Console output always looks a bit like this:

```
[4, 28, 62, 33, 11] // The unsorted array
Index thingy
new piv
Index thingy
new piv
Index thingy
new piv

Process is terminated due to `StackOverflowException`.
```

Comment: Run you program in the debugger, and when the StackOverflow occurs, inspect the call stack.

Comment: I fail to see a connection between the code you present and the algorithm C. A. R. Hoare presented as ACM ALGORITHM 64 QUICKSORT (beyond the classname). Is there a presentation of quicksort you tried to follow while coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a stack overflow error usually happens when you have a error in your recursion , ie a function keeps calling itself until there is no room left in the stack to hold all the references,

the only obvious candidate is

```
            **sort();**
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        **sort();**
        return -1;
    }
```

so either one or the other recursive calls is probably incorrect and needs removing and i suspect the issue will be resolved

EDIT:

as you are unable to debug your code
this is what a quick sort should look like

```
public int sort()
{
    qsort(0, toSort.Length - 1);
    return 0;
}

private void qsort( int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int pivot = Partition( left, right);

        if (pivot > 1)
        {
            qsort( left, pivot - 1);
        }
        if (pivot + 1 < right)
        {
             qsort( pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }
}
private int Partition( int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = toSort[left];
    while (true)
    {

        while (toSort[left] < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }

        while (toSort[right] > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        if (left < right)
        {
            if (toSort[left] == toSort[right]) return right;

            int temp = toSort[left];
            toSort[left] = toSort[right];
            toSort[right] = temp;


        }
        else
        {
            return right;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if left >= right do nothing

Comment: the problem being, i want to code a quicksort algorithm and that depends on recursion. i also cannot alter the code too much since, i want to compare all the algorithms

Comment: the you need to add the correct checks and balances to prevent the recursion occurring more than it should

Comment: i would suggest from your output `indexL > indexR` is incorrect otherwise "Index thingy" would be spamming the output stream, so either that clause is incorrect or the second call to sort is incorrect and you should just return a failed state rather than starting the sort again

Comment: According to the [Explaination](https://youtu.be/Hoixgm4-P4M?t=114) (the correct timestamp is entered, just pause it and read the text) I Followed, it is correct.

Comment: @ScarVite You never limit your search array and always sort `the sorted part`!!

Comment: And you only use `pivot` once. at the first calling method and left it alone. way?

Comment: thanks @AlirezaAhmadi i was working my way though for the exact point of failure but you beat me to it

Comment: Thank you both very much for you answers, it seems my understanding of the algorithm wasn't quite right, i've looked at it again and i believe i understood it (atleast it works now). You example also helped me understand it, for that reason, i'll accept your answer. Thank you both again

Comment: Shouldn't `if(pivot > 1`)` be `if (pivot -1 > left)` ?

Comment: (@rcgldr or left out altogether considering the missed `if (right <= left) return`.)

Comment: @rcgldr possibly i just grabbed an working example and tweaked it to fit the OP's model, other than checking it worked i didn't do complete edge testing

Comment: @MikeT - the issue is an extra call, not a failure. If the index returned by partition is anything other than 0, then even if left >= pivot-1, qsort calls itself (left, pivot-1), but then the `if(left < right)` catches it and just returns.

Answer (score 1):

This simple implementation of Hoare partition scheme demonstrates how to avoid stack overflow by recursing on the smaller partition, and looping back for the larger partition, an idea used in the original quicksort. Stack space complexity is limited to O(log2(n)), but worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

```
        static public void Quicksort(int [] a, int lo, int hi)
        {
            while(lo < hi){                 // while partition size > 1
                int p = a[(lo + hi) / 2];
                int i = lo, j = hi;
                i--;                        // Hoare partition
                j++;
                while (true)
                {
                    while (a[++i] < p) ;
                    while (a[--j] > p) ;
                    if (i >= j)
                        break;
                    int t = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = t;
                }
                i = j++;                    // i = last left, j = first right
                if((i - lo) <= (hi - j)){   // if size(left) <= size(right)
                    Quicksort(a, lo, i);    //   recurse on smaller partition
                    lo = j;                 //   and loop on larger partition
                } else { 
                    Quicksort(a, j, hi);    //   recurse on smaller partition
                    hi = i;                 //   and loop on larger partition
                }
            }
        }
```